# RGBDSLAMv2 REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-1] has died!

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on athlon i686 with ROS Kinetic and Kinect XBOX 360. I've installed rgbdslamv2 using install.sh script from the official [github](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2) repo. I've tried launching every launch file in /launch directory, but I always get the following error message:

```
======REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-1] has died!
process has died [pid 5855, exit code -11, cmd /home/doxub/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/doxub/.ros/log/61c2e24e-3806-11e8-8d8c-101f744a42d4/rgbdslam-1.log].
log file: /home/doxub/.ros/log/61c2e24e-3806-11e8-8d8c-101f744a42d4/rgbdslam-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[rgbdslam-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
```

I've seen that others also had similar issues, reported [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/215324/rgvdslam-v2-roslaunch-error-in-ubuntu-1404-ros-indigo/) and [here](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/issues/8).
I tried following this [instructions](https://hubpages.com/technology/Instructions-for-compiling-rgbdslam-v2-on-a-fresh-Ubuntu-1604-install-ros-kinetic-in-virtualbox) on how to compile Rgbdslam (V2) on a Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Install (Ros Kinetic) but without success. If someone is able to provide me with any insight on how to solve this problem it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287493/rgbdslamv2-required-process-%5Brgbdslam-1%5D-has-died!/) by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-04-06**:
Found [this](https://bit.ly/2IzYhfk) and at step 19. when I try to source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash I get the message "No such file or directory". Can anyone help, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should try the setup.bash in the document called "devel" .Or you go first check whether the setup.bash is in the "install" by $ cd ~/catkin_ws/install/    and  $ ls  .

---

Originally posted by [kwankitmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37625/kwankitmen/) with karma: 16 on 2018-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0